# How do I create named window partitions (aliases) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

The documentation for [PostgreSQL window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) seems to imply you can use the same named window in multiple places in your query. However, I can't figure out how do I create a named window?

```
SELECT first_value(vin) OVER( PARTITION BY vin ) AS w, first_value(make) OVER w
FROM inventory.vehicles
WHERE lot_Id = 9999 AND make is not null;
```

This is a joke query I'm trying to get the syntax to take, but I'm getting error:

> ERROR:  window "w" does not exist

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer was actually in the [`SELECT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) doc:

> **`WINDOW` Clause**
>
> The optional `WINDOW` clause has the
>   general form
>
> `WINDOW window_name AS ( window_definition ) [, ...]`

Here is an example,

```
SELECT first_value(vin) OVER w,
  first_value(make) OVER w
FROM inventory.vehicles
WHERE lot_Id = 9999
  AND make is not null
WINDOW w AS ( PARTITION by vin );
```