# Redshift PostgresQL syntax: is named window clause valid?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I suspect that Redshift does not support named windows, as Postgres has since at least version 8.4:

```
select stuff
       , stuff_category
       , sum(dollars) over W

from   table

window W as (partition by stuff_category)
```

However I would like to know definitively and I can't find a reference, or any post that says 'no we didn't implement this for very good reason yada yada.'

[The AWS Redshift SQL Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Window_function_synopsis.html) makes no mention of the 'window as' syntax - I suppose I should take this as an answer.

[Here's an SO answer relating to Postgres named windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454182/postgresql-named-windows)

[Here's the Postgres 8.4 documentation on `WINDOW AS ()` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html)

Comment: Don't read the Postgres documentation. Read the [Redshift manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Redshift does not support named windows.

As I have learned over time, the RS documentation will specify what is supported and if not mentioned its safe to assume it is not supported. There are no easter eggs or undocumented features to try and find, Legend of Zelda style.

[AWS Window Function Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Window_function_synopsis.html)

[AWS Docs Redshift and Postgres Comparison](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html) *This does not mention window functions, but is a good resource for this type of question.*